# How do I deal with two callbacks accessing a datastructure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, callback, firebase

**Update 2:**
*I think this is a better explanation:*

I have two callbacks, and each is filling up an array. I want to merge these arrays somehow. The naive way to do it is to wait until the arrays are filled, then merge with a for loop. I can't do that because there's no real way to check if the callbacks are "done".

The next step might be something like this: Each time an object is downloaded by a callback, it checks the merge array (called mixed), and sees if it contains a "partner" object. If it does: then merge into that partner object. If it doesn't, then insert that object.

I'm worried about race conditions: callback 1 sees the array is empty, decides to insert into it, but then control switches to callback 2, which inserts first. Callback 1 should now merge instead of insert, but when control switches back, it inserts instead.

What could help is if I could make an atomic "check and insert/merge" block of code. Is there a way to do that?

---

**Update 1:**
Now with code, and more words!

Thanks for your response, everyone. I went and tried to simplify the code as much as I could.

**Words:**

I have an array called mixed. Mixed should end up with: all objects of type (A), and if they have analogue objects of type (B) (also known as "private"s), they should be merged.

That means using two functions that use callbacks - getAllA and getAllB. Right now, I call both, wait a bit manually, then run a for loop that does that merging.

What I need to do is edit my code so that the merging happens in callbacks. However, I can't think of a way to do that merging in a way that doesn't create a race condition.

Naively, I might want to first fill up mixed with objects of type A, then go iterate through the B objects and merge them as needed. However, I can't do that because there's no way to see if you're "done" with on("contact_added") in firebase. What I think I want is a concurrent array structure, but I don't know how to use a built-in one. I'm worried about making my own because I don't know how to check to if I did it wrong. Race conditions are tricky like that.

**Now, the code:**
Here are the scripts you need to reference:

And here's what I paste into the javascript console:

```
    //Note: private ~~ B
    //      public ~ A

    var me = 'IWwypRHWpDmydd30o-v';
    var mixed = new Array();
    var mixedNames = new Array();
    var privates = new Object();

    var callbackB = function(snapshot){
        child = snapshot.val();
        privates[snapshot.name()] = child;
    };

    var callbackA = function(snapshot){
        var listRef = snapshot.ref();
        listRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot2) {
        child = snapshot2.val();
            mixedNames.push(snapshot2.name());
            mixed.push(child);
      });
    };

    var getAllB = function (callback, ownerid){
        var priv = new Firebase('http://gamma.firebase.com/innermost/project/private/' + ownerid);
        priv.on('child_added', function (snapshot){
        callback(snapshot);
      });
    };

    function getAllA(callback) {
      var pub = new Firebase('http://gamma.firebase.com/innermost/project/public');
      pub.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
          alert('snapshot does not exist.');
        }
        callback(snapshot);
      });
    }

    getAllA(callbackA);
    getAllB(callbackB, me);

    //////wait

    for (b in privates){
        var index = $.inArray(b, mixedNames);
        if (index < 0){ //if there is no record with this name
            mixed.push(privates[b]);
            mixedNames.push(b);
        }
        else{
            var pub = mixed[index];
            var mutt = returnMixed(pub, privates[b]);
            mixed.splice(index,1,mutt);
        }
    };
```

What I want to do is move the logic from the for loop into the callbacks, because if you run the for loop right away, the arrays won't be done downloading through the callbacks yet.

---

*The old entry:*

I have two callbacks accessing lists of data on Firebase.

Callback 1 gets objects of type A.
Callback 2 gets objects of type B.

My goal - have an array that properly merges objects of type A and B.

Most (but necessarily all) objects of type B have a "partner" object of type A.
A few objects of type A have a partner object of type B.

For each object pulled from Firebase, I want to see if their partner is in the array. If not, then insert. If so, then "merge" with the partner instead.

I can't think of a way to do this without a concurrent data structure - but I don't know how to do that in Javascript.

How can I either create that concurrent Array, or figure out a way to achieve my goal some other way?

Comment: It would help if you posted source code of what you have tried. Right now, the question is vague.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I tried to strip down the code to as basic as I could. I realize this is still a big chunk of code, sorry I couldn't simplify it more.

Comment: There are no race conditions in JavaScript, at least not as you have described them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="underscore.js"></script> <!-- or the lib of your choice -->
<script>

   function addWithPartner( value, id, type ) {
      var indexOfPartner = _.find(values, function(partner, i) {
         // logic for determining what a partner is goes here
         // for example: 
         return value.name == partner.name;
      });

      if( indexOfPartner >= 0 ) {
         merge( values, indexOfPartner, value );
      }
      else {
         values.push( value );
      }
   }

   function merge( list, index, value ) {
      // do whatever merge means here
      // for example:
      _.extend( list[index], value );
   }

   var FB = new Firebase(YOUR_URL);
   var values = [];

   FB.child('TYPEA').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      addWithPartner( snapshot.val(), snapshot.name(), 'typeA' );
   });

   FB.child('TYPEB').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      addWithPartner( snapshot.val(), snapshot.name(), 'typeB' );
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Kato. How does this deal with concurrency problems?

For example, TypeB calls add with partner, decides to push, then TypeA gets ownership of the thread, sees that it has no partner, and decides to push as well.

Comment: In JavaScript, they can't run concurrently. So when TypeA runs, it will see the partner. Threading is simulated, so you are guaranteed that your function will complete before another function is executed (excluding, of course, code that calls something asynchronous or runs setTimeout/setInterval)

Comment: @PersianExcursion hi, did you find answer for your question really. I think that concurency solved by Javascript engines with "Event Loop" it could not run two functions are sametime. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 1):

JS has nil values, right?  Anyway, if they don't, this answer is useless.

What I'd do is have a function on the main array which you pass an object and which checks to see if its partner is in the array.  If it is, it returns said object, otherwise it returns nil.  This way, you already have the object to perform the merge with if you need it.

Additionally, I wasn't exactly sure from how you worded it, but it seems you were worried about the concurrency becoming an issue (race conditions, overwrites, etc)?  If that's the case, this is the perfect example of a place to use a mutex (You can make your own pretty easily if js doesn't have them already). Just have the function I mentioned above lock at the beginning and unlock at the end, and you'll avoid reading out-of-date data.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jalaska. I'm worried about implementing the mutex incorrectly, because I don't know how to test whether it's working or not. Do you have any hints as to how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how concurrency works in js, but a (very) naive implementation would be something like this:

`var locked = false`
Then, in each function:
`while () {
if (!locked) {
locked = true;
break;
}
/* Do stuff with data */
locked = false;`

Comment: Mind you, this implementation would just use CPU like nobody's business.  Real mutexes as implemented in language libraries use slightly more intelligent ways of dealing with concurrency so time isn't wasted just going "is the mutex unlocked yet?"

Comment: If you want to learn more about mutexes in js, try here: http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/article.php/3592016

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand the details of the question, but it may help to know that javascript is single-threaded and so you never have to worry about true concurrency.  Your callbacks will always happen one at a time.

Thus you don't need a "concurrent data structure".  Most likely any data structure will work since there is no concurrency in javascript. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in earlier answers, javascript is single threaded when limited to the main window; even if a function is called asychronously, its execution will be "atomic" (not interrupted). Thus you can't have race conditions.

However, dealing with the problem " I can't do that because there's no real way to check if the callbacks are "done"", try http://www.megiddo.ch/jcon-q-rency that provides a wait/notify(All) mechanism. I use it to do operations quite like yours.

With it, you can delay the execution of a function until a certain condition is satisfied. That is your "//////wait". When getAllA() and getAllB() are done, they can notify a waiting function that is in charge of executing the for (b in privates){..} loop.